# How to inject class in nonController class with ninject

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ninject

I set up "Ninject" in my asp.mvc project. And it works fine each controller get its dependency classes. But I have one class in mvc project that is not controller. It's a simple class that extends "MembershipProvider" (because I have made custom membership) and I need to inject "UserRepository" class in it.
In a NinjectControlelrFactory I bint it:

```
private void AddBindings()
{
ninjectKernel.Bind<IUserRepository>().To<UserRepository>().WithConstructorArgument(
                "connectionString", ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connStr"].ConnectionString);
}
```

But how to get it from non controller class?
PS
I can't inject through constructor.

I have some solution but I don't know how 'clean' it is:

```
using (IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel())
            {
                kernel.Bind<IUserRepository>()
                    .To<UserRepository>()
                    .WithConstructorArgument("connectionString", "ttttttttttttt");
                //var tc = kernel.Get<IUserRepository>();
                this.userRepository = kernel.Get<IUserRepository>();
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Property Injection. Register your `MembershipProvider` in the Ninject and use [Property injection](http://ninject.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Injection%20Patterns).

You will need to instantiate `MembershipProvider` via ninject context.

Check these articles.

[Property Injection in ASP.NET MVC with Ninject](http://www.emadibrahim.com/2008/08/29/property-injection-in-aspnet-mvc-with-ninject/)

[Injecting properties in Ninject 2 without 'Inject' attribute](http://www.joaoalmeida.info/2010/07/injecting-properties-in-ninject-2-without-inject-attribute/)

Comment: Thanks this will help me. But can you check my updated question. I write something and it works but I am not sure that it is a valid method of getting dependency class?

Comment: If this code in the your `MembershipProvider` - it'snot dependency injection, because you use your implementation type `UserRepository` here and it's already dependent from it.

Comment: Yeah you are right. I changed code to property injection but I always get 'object reference not set' I can;t figure why :(

Comment: Probably you will find answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2574706/ninject-giving-nullreferenceexception) which already was asked on stackoverflow. Any details would be helpful.

Comment: Ok I find that when I add this code in binding section (Global.asax) "Kernel.Inject(Membership.Provider);" it works in combination with Injectable proeprties. Is this valid approach?

Comment: all initialization of the IoC almost always a placed in Global.asax